# How to go to another page after a function executes flask python

Tags: python, flask

I have a function called **getTableData()** which runs another function **get_table()** and based on that  **get_table()** output final function is called which renders a template and also routes to a different page.
So the problem is its not routing to a different url (**/tabdata**) from **get_final()** function

**Flask code:**

```
@app.route('/api/getTableData', methods=['POST'])
def getTableData():
    value = request.json['value']
    value=value[:8]
    url="https://some.com"+value
    df_time=get_table(url)
    return get_final(df_time)

def get_table(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 
    driver.get(url) 
    abv = pd.read_html(driver.find_element(By.ID,"frm_hist").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
    df_time = pd.DataFrame(abv)  
    return df_time

@app.route("/tabdata")  
def get_final(df_time):
    return render_template("new.html",df_time = df_time)
```

**Code Explanation:**

I am using the **value** from **value** variable then concat 2 strings to make the url and then passing the url to another function named **get_table()** which goes to that url and webscrapes the table and converts it into python dataframe. 
So using the returned python dataframe **get_final()** is called to render the template in a html file and also route to the **/tabdata** url. Everything is working well except the page is not routing to that url

Comment: why have you added both tags `django` and `flask`?

Comment: Hey sorry just thought users who would know django would also know flask

Comment: it could be for some users but not for all

Comment: Yeah noted..........

Answer (score 0):

In `getTableData()`, change

```
return get_final(df_time)
```

to

```
return redirect(url_for("get_final", df_time=df_time))
```

In `get_final()`, change

```
@app.route("/tabdata")  
def get_final(df_time):
    return render_template("new.html",df_time = df_time)
```

to

```
@app.route("/tabdata/<df_time>")
def get_final(df_time):
    return render_template("new.html", df_time=df_time)
```

Although your redirected URL will look something like this; "http://localhost/tabdata/16606505". If this is not preferred, you can always redirect for GET request with query parameters (which will look like this; "http://localhost/tabdata&data=16606505") or redirect for POST request which will not show the `df_time` parameter in browser history.

Comment: TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable is the error I am getting @Mirza Atli

Comment: Edited my message. Corrected "url_for" part.

Comment: still not working. I got a 404

Comment: @qcoder I'm sorry that I couldn't help you. I'll try to recreate the error later if the issue is not resolved. In the meantime, I'm just curious why wouldn't you `render_template` in the `getTableData`. Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: Because I tried and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a redirect:

```py
from flask import redirect

@app.route("/tabdata/<df_time>")
def get_final(df_time):
    return redirect("http://www.example.com", code=200)
```

Comment: Why didnt u mention the render_template part. How does the code know which html file to go for? @ilyasbbu

Comment: `redirect`  redirects to another url, You can mention to which url to redirect not the template.

Comment: its not working i guess'

Answer (score 0):

Use [`redirect`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.redirect) and use it with [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Flask.url_for) in case you decide to change your routes in the future. You also need to change your view function `get_final`

```py
from flask import redirect, url_for


@app.route('/api/getTableData', methods=['POST'])
def getTableData():
    value = request.json['value']
    value = value[:8]
    url = "https://some.com"+value
    df_time = get_table(url)
    return redirect(url_for('get_final', df_time=df_time))

def get_table(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 
    driver.get(url) 
    abv = pd.read_html(driver.find_element(By.ID,"frm_hist").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
    df_time = pd.DataFrame(abv)  
    return df_time

@app.route("/tabdata/<df_time>") # notice change here!
def get_final(df_time):
    return render_template("new.html", df_time=df_time)
```

Comment: This is not working. Its not navigating to that tabdata url

Comment: @qcoder, are you getting any errors?

Comment: @qcoder, I am not certain why you want to pass a dataframe (assuming it is converted to a string properly)

Comment: I am able to get the data but also getting a 404

Comment: Here I will be using  render_template("new.html", df_time=df_time.to_html()

Comment: @qcoder, did you update the route to "/tabdata/<df_time>"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249128/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-qcoder).